# How to read a CSV file, remove a column, and replace the file

Tags: java, file, java-11, opencsv, csvreader

I have a CSV file in my local folder. I would like to read it, remove a column, and replace the file in the same folder.

Actual sample data:

```
ID,EMAIL,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME             
99999,TestEmail@fakeemail.com,TEST_FNAME,TEST_LNAME
33333,TestEmail@fakeemail.com,TEST_FNAME,TEST_LNAME
```

Expected data from the sample data:

```
ID,EMAIL,FIRSTNAME             
99999,TestEmail@fakeemail.com,TEST_FNAME
33333,TestEmail@fakeemail.com,TEST_FNAME
```

In this case, I would like to remove the column `LASTNAME`. Can it be done effectively in Java?

Comment: Yes. You need to rewrite the whole file though. What part of this are you stuck on?

Comment: @f1sh I was able to read the csv file, but couldn't figure out the logic to remove the column.

Answer (score 0):

As in your example, you want to remove last column.
So easiest way would be to substring from beginning to last index of separator `,`.

```
line.substring(0,line.lastIndexOf(","))
```

Full example:

```
try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(
                     Paths.get("path_to_output_file")))) {
    Files.lines(Paths.get("path_to_input_file")).map(line ->    line.substring(0,line.lastIndexOf(","))).forEach(pw::println);
}
```

If you need to remove other column, you may you split `line.split(",")` and than concatenate skipping column you want.

Comment: It's dangerous (and often wrong) to split CSV lines using `String.split`. The lines can be like `column one,column two,"column three,not four","column four,not three"`. A simple `String.split` would treat such data incorrectly. Use a proper CSV parser instead.